# How to find xpath which have span in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Below is the inspect element. I need to figure out the xpath so that, cursor should click on filter icon.

[image]

I have tried below xpath, but it doesn't work. I need to specify column name 'Investment Description', because page has lot of filter icons.

```
//div[@class='ag-header-cell-label' ]/child::span[@class='ag-header-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden']
```

Comment: add your url in detail?

Comment: Might be you took different xpath value

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the below `xpath`. Hope this will identify the element you are after.

```
//div[@class='ag-header-cell-label']/span[text()='Investment Description']/following::span[1]
```

OR

```
//div[@class='ag-header-cell-label']/span[contains(.,'Investment Description')]/following::span[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.//span[.='Investment Description']/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: I used this xpath and its working, but it is giving many results. Can you please specify class name in this, so that it would be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```
//span[contains(text(),'Investment Description')]/parent::div/descendant::span[contains(@class,'filter')]
```

Going forward kindly [avoid posting code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), the chance you will get comprehensive answer will be much higher.

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)